# The action 'destroy' could not be found for ActivitiesController despite being defined

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

For some reason I am getting error "The action 'destroy' could not be found for ActivitiesController" when trying to destroy an object:

view:

```
<% @activities.each do |a|%>
...

  <td><%= link_to 'Delete', activity_path(a.id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you    sure?"} %></td>
...

<% end %>
```

controller:

```
def destroy
  @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
  @activity.destroy
  redirect_to activity_path
end
```

What could be the issue?

ruby: 2.6.3p62
Rails: 6.0.2.1

Comment: Can you paste your full activities_controller file, filename and routes file please, it could well be looking at a different controller

Comment: And please, also post the relevant routes for the activities 

Comment: You're more than likely missing `resources :activities` in your routes file.

Comment: please also post the logs in addition to what @Mark has asked for

Comment: I had to pot it to repl sicne sicne the it was too big. 
https://repl.it/@rafaelkukawski/Activites

Comment: Why do you have 2 `destroy` functions defined?

Comment: That code is an absolute mess and the error is caused by an extra `end` keyword. Plus the fact that are defining the destroy method twice. Start by cleaning it up and fixing the indentation so that you can actually read your own code.